# How to merge categories in pandas series data into one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have pandas Series which looks like this:

```
education:       number_of_appearances:

HS-grad:         15784

Some-college:    10878

Bachelors:        8025

Masters:          2657

11th:             1812

10th:             1389

7th-8th:           955

9th:               756

12th:              657

5th-6th:           509

1st-4th:           247
```

It comes from dataset adults from UCI. My question is how can I merge categories so I can have something like this:

```
HS-grad:         15784

... 

(1st-4th, 5th-6th) : 756
```

Something like R forcats maybe would be good for that approach? Hovewer I can't find any good answers for that.

I edited for better clarity. I want to decide which categories would be merge, so tools which would merge by quantity of appearences are not ok.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output with better clarification.?

Comment: Expected output should be Pandas Series, but data in it should be changed. Here is the code that illustrates what Im trying to achieve: import pandas as pd

     data = pd.Series({"Category1": 1, "Category2": 1, "Category3": 1})


data_after_merge = pd.Series({"(Category1,Category2)": 2, "Category3": 1})
                   .I want to end with something like data_after_merge

Comment: So it is: Category: Number of appearances of category